# Possibly incorrect spider/exporter example code in scrapy docs

Tags: python, scrapy

Can someone check whether the code below is correct?
The code is found at
http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/0.14/topics/exporters.html

I believe it is incorrect because:

- The class keeps track of multiple simultaneously open files for multiple spiders, however:
- The exporter (which depends on the file) is overwritten each time a new spider is opened.

Thanks for any assistance.

```
class XmlExportPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        self.files = {}

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_products.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question should be asked in [scrapy-users group](http://groups.google.com/group/scrapy-users).

AFAIK, since v0.14 Scrapy doesn't suppport multiple spiders in one process ([related discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scrapy-users/L9WNLR83BeI/discussion)), so this code will work fine. And obvious fix for multiple spiders is to make `exporters` dict with `spider` keys:

```
class XmlExportPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        self.files = {}
        self.exporters = {}

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_products.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporters[spider] = XmlItemExporter(file)
        self.exporters[spider].start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporters[spider].finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporters[spider].export_item(item)
        return item
```

Comment: Thanks, that was enlightening